# selecting records based on datetime column changes the data in the datetime column ..very strange

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin

So i have a table that has multiple date time columns and i am trying to select certain records based on a certain date using

```
SELECT * FROM `posdata` WHERE `CommissionDate` >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
```

the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `posdata` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DISTYNAME` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,    
  `ENDCUST` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MFGCUST` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXTPRICE` double DEFAULT NULL,  
  `POSPERIOD` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `PAYMENTDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTY` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNITCOST` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNITPRICE` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMISSION` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `SALESORDER` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PO` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POLineItem` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTRYDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `AdjustedCommission` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerPart-NO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CommissionDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXTCOST` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `posdata`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `CommissionDate` (`CommissionDate`);
ALTER TABLE `posdata` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `posdata_endcustomer_index` (`ENDCUST`);
```

a very weird thing happens, it returns all the fields as required, but the CommissionDate column has only '2019-01-01 00:00:00' as the date. The actual CommissionDate column in the database has only '2016-01-01 00:00:00' as the data.

I am using phpmyadmin to to run this query and have used the search filter on that and it always gives me the same result whether i run it thorough a php script or phpmyadmin. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You must have some rows with CommissionDate = '2019-01-01 00:00:00' in your table.

Comment: That's such a simple query that the result must be true.

Comment: Can you share your result screen shots with the `CommistionDate` date information ?

Answer (score 0):

In your query `SELECT * FROM 'posdata'` means get all the fields from the table post data and then the next WHERE clause applies.If you only want to get the data from `CommissionDate` column

**Change Your Query to**

```
SELECT `CommissionDate` FROM `posdata`
```

In the way you get the desired data.